# Laravel direct access file load to javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, nginx

Greeting. I have a laravel run under nginx.

I have a JSON string stored as a file at /app/Libraries/json.js

How can I read it at client browsers' javascript?

I tried

```
    var myObject = JSON.parse('<? echo file_get_contents(app_path() . "/Libraries/json.js") ?>', reviver);
```

but it keeps prompt errors to me at console.

If it helps, the json string i need to read is the ISO 3166 country code json files. I have just uploaded the file at [HERE](http://orbb.li/region.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably don't use JSON.parse. tho I would need to see your json.js string to be sure.

EDIT:

used this code successfully (saved that js file in same folder under temp.js)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var t = <?php echo file_get_contents("temp.js"); ?>;
      window.addEventListener("load",function(){
        alert(t[0].ASI.code);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry this should have been posted as a comment first

Comment: It is the ISO 3166 country code json files. I have just uploaded the file at [HERE](http://orbb.li/region.js)